# Is there a way to call multiple inherited overrides of a function?

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

I have an Item base class, and a few subclasses that all overwrite a function 'update()'.

```
class Item {
   virtual void update()
   {
      ;
   }
}

class BomblikeItem: public Item {
   int fuseTimer=10;
   void update()
   {
      fuseTimer--;
      if(fuseTimer==0)
         explode();
   }
}

class HeartlikeItem: public Item {
   void update()
   {
      beat();
   }
}

class RoboticItem: public Item {
   int energy=10;
   void update()
   {
      if(energy==0)
         shutdown();
   }
}
```

If I try to make a new child object that inherits from two or more of those classes (such as a robotic heart), I get an error that update() is being found in multiple base classes. I don't want to override update() for each possible case of mix-and-match, but I want to be able to make new items that still function like all of them.

My current solution is to move all the alternate update() functions into the base Item class and determine when it should be called based on if the current item is marked to be of that type of class, but it feels very wrong / inefficient:

```
class Item {
   ,,,
   void update()
   {
      if(isType(Bomblike))
         Bomblike realForm=this->dynamicCastTo(bomb)
         realForm->fuseTimer--;
         if(realForm->fuseTimer==0)
            realForm->explode();

      if(isType(Heartlike)
         ,,,
      ,,,
   }
}

class BomblikeItem: public Item {
   int fuseTimer=10;
}

,,,
```

Are there better ways to go about this? Is there a way to sequentially call all inherited versions of a single overwritten function like 'update()'?

Comment: You should be able to specify which `update()` you are talking about by prefixing it with the class name, like `BomblikeItem::update()` or `HeartlikeItem::update()`

Comment: You better to 1) Declare the `update()` function as virtual, 2) Propagate `update()` function call from a child to its parent, 3) Avoid diamond like inheritance.

Comment: I think it is possible by casting the object to the corresponding type

Comment: Maybe an event handling system is what you really need? I would not recommend going the multiple inheritance route for this kind of behavior modeling, I think you will face a lot of pain.

Comment: Is it a typo that you don't declare the `update()` function as `virtual`?

Comment: You wrote you don't want to overwrite update in all join-classes, do you mean reimplementing or even the following?

    void update() {
        BomblikeItem::update();
        HeartlikeItem::update();
    }

Another option might be composition: Have a base class that has a vector of properties and the update method calls all update methods of the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about your current solution, it is going to be difficult to maintain/ extend such code. Ideally `Item` class should be abstract class with all its method pure virtual methods. But if it solves your issue then you may still have 'update` as just virtual method with base implementation.

To deal with Diamond problem you might want to make `Item` virtual base class of its derived classes.

```
class BomblikeItem: virtual public Item 
                    ~~~~~~~
{
    // ... 
}

class HeartlikeItem: virtual public Item 
                     ~~~~~~
{
    // ... 
}
```